# how to get a row from mysql and use it in android

Tags: php, android

I want to retreive from mysql database a row from a table that contains name,last_name,image BLOB, i already could retreive the image from the database and use it in android apps using DecodeInoutStrem. but don't want just the image, i want to get the image with its name and last name. how can i do that ?

this is **DoInBackground** methode i use to retreive image from mysql via php(**load_image_from_db.php**) URL:

```
@Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String add1 = "http://192.168.1.11/save/load_image_from_db.php?id=1";
            URL url;
            Bitmap image = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(add1);
                    HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
            return image;
        }
    }
```

**load_image_from_db.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image,image_type FROM images where id = $id";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));;

$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');

if ($result['image_type'] == 'php') {
            echo ( $result['image']);
            } else if ($result['image_type'] == 'android') {
            echo base64_decode( $result['image'] );
        }
mysqli_close($con);
//stripslashes ($result['image']);
//echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
//echo base64_encode( $result['image'] );
}
?>
```

Comment: create api in php and then use that for retrieving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Java side:

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(inputStream);
String response = "";
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
     response += scanner.nextLine();
}
```

You will need to output something in the PHP file, a simple echo on the interested fields will do it as it outputs on the response.

Comment: by this way i can just read String result so i use two php url, one who displays String and use scanner to read them in android apps, and another php script who displays image and use decodeInputStream to use it in android apps?